# Session undefined with express-session in other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use express-session, but it doesn't work as it should.

I have declared a session variable inside a function and now I am calling another function after this function and want to get the data from the session variable but it says that it is undefined.

What is wrong?

```
checkUserMojangAPI();
reg2NewUserData();


function checkUserMojangAPI() {
   // Session declaring
   req.session.email = email;
   return
}

function reg2NewUserData() {
    console.log(req.session.email) // is undefined
  }
```

If I use a console.log(req.session.email) directly after its declaration it works.

Thanks Raphael

Comment: What happens if you log `req.session.email` in between the function calls?

Comment: This was the solution for me also :)